# Bigquery : Daylight saving for Greenwich timezone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert the timestamp from UTC time  in to **Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London** time zone. This is Greenwich time zone in big query. As I read Greenwich and UTC are same(UTC+0)
But in **Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London**   during summer time April to September this become UTC+1 due to day light savings.

When I am converting below timestamp in Greenwich I am not getting 1 hour offset
see below query

```
select TIMESTAMP('2021-05-31 23:00:00', "Greenwich")TIMESTAMP
```

[image]

My understanding is that if the timestamp is from APRIL to OCT big query will convert the timestamp  like below automatically

[image]

Can anybody suggest how can I convert the below timestamp as per daylights saving in big query particularly from Greenwich? Or am I missing something here which I need to know ?

Comment: You're confusing GMT/UTC (which is always offset 0), with the timezone Europe/London (which is GMT/UTC in winter, and GMT+1/UTC+1 in summer).

Comment: If you are trying to convert UTC time to local time considering Daylight saving time use this query -> `SELECT DATETIME("2021-05-31 23:00:00", "Europe/London") as date;`. Bigquery does the conversion considering the DST of local time. The output would be `2021-06-01T00:00:00`. Please check this link for more information on the [DATETIME function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime).